# Updating row changes created_at column

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

When I update my row with the query below, it changes not only the `updated_at` column for the row, but also the `created_at` column. Why? How can I prevent this so that it *only* changes the `updated_at` column (as it should)?

```
Post::where('id', Input::get('post_id'))
    ->where('user_id', getUserID())
    ->update(array('message' => Input::get('message')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = Post::where('id', Input::get('post_id'))
    ->where('user_id', getUserID())->get();
$post->message = Input::get('message');
$post->save();
```

Comment: Does the same thing. Still changes `created_at`. :/

Comment: What is your table definition (migration file)?

Comment: I have no migration file.